# Increase limit of "Text to columns"

Tags: excel

I have 2003 words in a cell which I want to separate in to different cells of different columns by using the function "Text to columns" but its doing up to 230 columns only. Can anybody help to know how to increase its limit? or what function I should add for this.

Note I am using excel 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I can replicate your experience. When I create a simple test (a delimited string of 250 items), the `TextToColumns` method creates 500 columns of data:

```
Sub Test()
'
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim r As Range

Set r = [A1]

For i = 1 To 500

s = s & i & ","

Next

r.Value = s

r.TextToColumns , xlDelimited, , , , , True

Debug.Print r.End(xlToRight).Column

End Sub
```

If you are not able to resolve it, then here is an alternative.  You could split the cell value in to an array and print the array to the worksheet.

Assumes the string is comma-delimited, and the cell is "A1".  Modify as needed.

```
Sub MyTextToColumns()

Dim r As Range
Dim s As String
Dim v As Variant


Set r = Range("A2")
s = r.Value
v = Split(s, ",")

Range("A3").Resize(1, UBound(v) + 1).Value = v

End Sub
```

There is a limit on the size of an array but I think it is upwards of 30,000.

Comment: Giving the error "text extends beyond worksheet" and not exceeding 256 columns, alternative is also not working

Comment: Well there are limitations imposed by your worksheet and the file type. Excel 2003 and prior has limit of 256 columns in a worksheet if you are working with a legacy file, this is expected. What would you like to happen in these cases?

Comment: I am using excel 2007, is it have the same limitation?

Comment: Is the file an XLS or XLSM/XLSX?

Comment: And in which column is the cell you are trying to split?

Comment: File was saved in excel 97-2003, what you suggest in which type I should save?

Comment: Try saving as an XLSX/XLSM and re-running? Those file types should support 16,384 columns of data.